# PostGres joins Using JSONB

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have two tables which look like such

```
Organizations
Id (primary_key. big int)
Name (text)

CustomInformations
Id (primary_key. big int)
ConnectedIdentifiers (JSONB)
Info (text)
```

`CustomInformations`'s `ConnectedIdentifiers` column contains a `JSONB` structure which looks like

`{ 'organizations': [1,2,3] }`

This means that there's an array of organizations with those ids `1, 2, 3,` which are related to that particular `CustomInformation`

I'm trying to do a `JOIN` where given a `CustomInformation` Id will also get me all the `Organizations` names

I tried this after looking at some examples:

```
SELECT * FROM CustomInformations ci
INNER JOIN Organizations o on jsonb_array_elements(ci.ConnectedIdentifiers->'19') = o.id
WHERE
   ci.id = 5
```

I got an error `No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Is this the right approach? And if so what is wrong with my syntax?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `jsonb_array_elements()` in this way because the function returns set of rows. It should be placed in a lateral join instead. Use `jsonb_array_elements_text()` to get array elements as text and cast these elements to `bigint:`

```
select ci.*, o.*
from custominfo ci
-- lateral join 
cross join jsonb_array_elements_text(ci.connectedidentifiers->'organizations') ar(elem)
join organizations o 
on elem::bigint = o.id
where ci.id = 5
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the cross join?

Comment: In fact it is a lateral join (not a cartesian product). Read about this [in the documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM)